# How to add an element to the list in the dictionary in python?

Tags: python

```
import itertools    
from collections import defaultdict


my_tree={'parent':'Smith', 'children':[{'parent':'Connor', 'children':[{'parent':'Alexis','children':
[{'parent':'Joe', 'children':[{'parent':'Clark','children':[]}]}]},{'parent':'Sue','children':[]}]},
{'parent':'Cooper', 'children':[{'parent':'Max','children':[{'parent':'Luis', 'children':[]},]},
{'parent':'Elvis', 'children':[]},{'parent':'Steven', 'children':[]}]}]}         


class Person:                                                             
    ID = itertools.count()
    def __init__(self, name, parent=None, level=0):
        self.id = self.__class__.ID.next()                                              
        self.parent = parent
        self.name = name    
        self.level = level
        self.children = []                          


def createTree(d, parent=None, level=0):
    if d:                                           
        member = Person(d['parent'], parent, level)
        level = level + 1
        member.children = [createTree(child, member, level) for child in d['children']]
        return member   


t = createTree(my_tree)          
def printout(parent, indent=0):
    print '\t'*indent, parent.name
    for child in parent.children:
        printout(child, indent+1)        
printout(t)
```

---

I want to add elements into the list in my_tree dictionary. For example, I want to add a new child for Sue.

Comment: I think you should review the `my_tree` structure

Comment: As it can have many people called "Sue" in the family, you need a unique identifier for each people to be able to update their children without problem.

Comment: I think I need to use a unique ID. I am thinking like you . How do I do that? @LoïcG.

Comment: You can use `uuid` module for that with an object (class) for each person

Answer (score 1):

What about something like :

```
my_tree[parentname].append(child)
```

?

But your dictionnary structure is weirdly designed. Is `Smith` the parent of `Connor` or the parent of `Connor`'s parent?

Perhaps something like:

```
{
    "Luke": {"parents": ["Anakin", "Padme"], "children" : []},
    "Leia": {"parents": ["Anakin", "Padme"], "children" : ["Ben"]}
}
```

would make more sense?

Comment: OP asked for adding a new child for "Sue" not how to basically add an element to a dict. How he is supposed to do with your answer ?

Comment: I do not know how to make such an attachment in my production @vmonteco

Answer (score -1):

Well your dictionary is structured quite weird.. But appending to a list within a dictionary is no stranger than appending directly to a list..

```
myDict = {"Sue": ["Connor"]}
myDict["Sue"].append("Barbara")

print(myDict)

>>> {"Sue": ["Connor", "Barbara"]}
```

Comment: I did not give a minus rating. But it is not unfortunately as you said. Try it. @BartekSpitza

Comment: Well I find your dictionary hard to read. Can you try to explain what you are trying to do? @Michael

Comment: I'm trying to make a family tree. The reading is a little complicated. The lists in the dictionary indicate the children. You can understand code better if you run it. @Bartek Spitza